# BootStrap Grid issue with fixed container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, width

I am using bootstrap composing my view, I have below code in my view, `the container will be a fixed value of 980px`, the `navbar should have a width of 242px`, But now the width of navbar was calculated by bootstrap automatically with a width of 245px.

Are there any way to do the customization to make the navbar have a fixed width of 242px?

```
    <div class="row" >
        <div id="navbar" class="col-sm-3  col-lg-3  navbar">             

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9  col-lg-9  content">
            content
            <!-- insert nested grid here -->
        </div>          
    </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: don't include bootstrap classes in navbar, instead, just place any custom class made by you...done!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this :-

```
<div id="navbar" class="col-sm-3  col-lg-3  navbar">
```

With this :-

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar">

.navbar{
width: 242px;
}
```

Comment: bingo...exactly...+1 mate!! :D

Comment: @NoobEditor Good...You are intelligent..! :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div class="row" >
            <div id="navbar" class="col-sm-3  col-lg-3  navbar" style="width:242px;">             

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9  col-lg-9  content">
                content
                <!-- insert nested grid here -->
            </div>          
        </div>      
    </div>
```

Comment: no idea but changing class will make many problems because he using bootstrap.

Comment: `col-lg-` is for `Large devices Desktops (≥1200px)`, so it is going to cause a problem....and since BS is just a compilation of css and not a framework, you can always ignore to use its classes....simple!! :)